# How to make changes in registry immediately appear on the disk (windows 8)?

Tags: registry, flush

In windows 8 if you change registry, those changes will not appear immediately on the disk.
Found explanation of this behaviour here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784761

If you want to change this behavior you can use
RegFlushKey function

The question is how to use it?
private static readonly IntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = new IntPtr(-2147483646);

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int RegFlushKey(IntPtr hKey);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegFlushKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
}
```

This is the way I was trying to implement it, but after this code registry changes are not on the file system.

Please, point me if I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [pInvoke website](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/RegFlushKey.html):

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegFlushKey")]
public static extern int RegFlushKey(IntPtr hKey);

const UInt32 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 0x80000000;
const UInt32 HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
const UInt32 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
const UInt32 HKEY_USERS = 0x80000003;

public static void CommitRegistry()
{
    IntPtr hkeyLocalMachine = new IntPtr(unchecked((int)HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE));
    RegFlushKey(hkeyLocalMachine);
}
```